# JS not accepted by Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using a third-party tool which uses [mediator-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mediator-js) and everything is working if I'm just running the third-party tool by it self. When I try to run it in my Angular application, I get a error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Mediator is not a constructor
```

Which comes from the initialisation of the [mediator-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mediator-js) lib.

This is done like this in my third-party tool, which is pure JS and not typed:

```
var Mediator
var mediator;
Mediator = require("mediator-js").Mediator;
  mediator = new Mediator();

mediator.subscribe("test", function (vals) {
});

module.exports = mediator;
```

I'm not sure why it is working out, but not inside of my application. Do I have to configure TypeScript somehow to accept a JS?

Comment: Is this error run time? Or coming from the typescript compiler?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck It's quite clearly a run-time error.

Comment: It's a runtime error. It's compiling fine without any noise.

Comment: This cannot be reproduced unless you show us how you use `mediator-js` in your Angular application.

Comment: @torazaburo, It wasn't for me unfortunately. But thank you.

Comment: For some bizarre reason, removing the `.Mediator` from the `Mediator = require("mediator-js").Mediator;` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it is TypeScript you're aiming for, then you can neaten this up a little bit.

```
import Mediator from 'mediator-js';

export var mediator = new Mediator();
```

Your code looks very much like regular JavaScript though.  If that is what you're after, then try:

```
var Mediator = require('mediator-js');
var mediator = new Mediator();

module.exports = mediator;
```

Comment: Yes, the third party lib is regular JS, but it used to work until they have added mediator-js. It seems to me that TS is very strict, when it comes to read JS. I use other JS libs and they all work perfectly fine.